# How can I use overloaded case class constructors and still use pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, overloading, case-class

I was trying to learn pattern matching when I found this example. It seems that case class pattern matching is not working with overloaded case class constructors.

```
case class MyClass(var first:String, var last:String){
 def this(first: String) = this(first, "")
 override def toString = "First: "+ first + " Last:" +last
}

val myClassTwo = new MyClass("a", "b")
myClassTwo match {
   case MyClass(a,b) => println("two constructor matched")
   case MyClass(a) => println("one constructor matched")
   case _ => println("Not matched")
  }
```

I am getting compilation error "wrong number of arguments for pattern MyClass(first:String, last:String) at "case MyClass(a)" line. I was expecting pattern matching to work for the overloaded constructor, but it's not working as I expected. Could anyone please explain this behaviour?

Also I am getting wrong result with one constructor parameter.

```
 val myClassOne = new MyClass("a")      
  myClassOne match {
   case MyClass(a,b) => println("two constructor matched")
   case _ => println("Not matched")
  }
```

This produces "two constructor matched" even if `myClassOne` has only one agrument. Please explain.

Answer (score 17):

To understand what's going on, you need to know that pattern matching on case classes is syntax for a method called `unapply`. This is explained in [A Tour of Scala: Extractor Objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112).

Using the REPL, you can see that the compiler has generated an `unapply` method on the companion object of `MyClass`, which corresponds to the parameters of the main constructor:

```
scala> MyClass.unapply _
res0: MyClass => Option[(String, String)] = <function1>
```

But the compiler will not generate extractors for any auxiliary constructors that you define (using `this()`). If you try to define an additional `unapply` yourself you'll see why - you can't overload the method with another that has exactly the same parameters (an instance of `MyClass`).

When you create an instance using the auxiliary constructor, `new MyClass("a")`, that is still a fully constructed instance of `MyClass` and hence the generated `unapply` method is still valid. The pattern in `case MyClass(a,b)` will match `a` to `"a"`, and `b` to `""`.

Answer (score 3):

Ben's answer is just perfect..

You can still find a way around to match your `case class` by using `_` for the parameters you don't care...

```
myClassOne match {
   case MyClass("a","b") => println("two constructor matched")
   case MyClass("a",_) => println("one constructor matched")
   case _ => println("Not matched")
  }
```